# Get Auth0 access token via command line

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I am force to use an unergonomic web site (let’s call it `zzz`) that uses auth0 for authentication, and a REST API internally, and I have a strong desire to use the API directly.

Using the browser inspector, I can see how that API works, and if I use the JWT Access Token (transmitted using `Authorization: Bearer`) that I find there, I can script access to API.

The problem I am facing is getting such a JWT access token via auth0, given my username and password.

When I use the browser-based login, I see that `zzz` redirects me to

```
https://zzz.eu.auth0.com/login
   ?state=g6…mo
   &client=uz…6j
   &protocol=oauth2
   &response_type=token%20id_token
   &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffoo.zzz.com%2Fcallback
   &scope=openid%20read%3Amore%20scopes…
   &audience=zz-api-prod
   &nonce=0G…L7
   &auth0Client=ey…n0%3D
```

(line breaks for your convenience)

I can now manually enter username and password, and get logged in, which seems to perform these steps:

- A `POST` to

  ```
  https://zzz.eu.auth0.com/usernamepassword/login
  ```

  with a body of

  ```
  { "client_id":"uz…6j",
    "redirect_uri":"https://foo.zzz.com/callback",
    "tenant":"zzz",
    "response_type":"token id_token"
    "connection":"zzz-production-users",
    "username":"…",
    "password":"…",
    "nonce":"0G…L7",
    "state":"g6…mo",
    "sso":true,
    "_intstate":"deprecated",
    "_csrf":"fb…KI",
    "audience":"zzz-api-prod",
    "auth0Client":"ey…n0=",
    "scope":"openid read:stores more:scopes …",
    "protocol":"oauth2"
  }
  ```

  and a response of

  ```
  <form method="post" name="hiddenform" action="https://zzz.eu.auth0.com/login/callback">
    <input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0">
    <input type="hidden" 
           name="wresult" 
           value="ey…tE">
    <input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="…">
    <noscript>
        <p>
            Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.
        </p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </noscript>
   </form>
  ```
- The JS on the login page seems to press that submit button, causing a POST to

  ```
  https://zzz.eu.auth0.com/login/callback
  ```

  which redirects to

  ```
  https://foo.zzz.com/callback
     #access_token=ey…7Q
     &scope=openid%20read%3Amore%20scopes…
     &expires_in=7200
     &token_type=Bearer
     &state=%7B%7D
     &id_token=ey…Sg
  ```

  … which contains the precious access token that I want.

Trying to script this precise flow, which would involve parsing the returned HTML to extract the `wctx` and `wresult` arguments, is quite tedious.

So my question is:

Is there a way to get the `access_token` some other way that is more convenient to script using just command line curl, or maybe some simple python code/library?

I have tried various things that I found on the auth0 documentation website (e.g. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant#realm-support), but could not get them to work; presmably because they need to be explicitly enabled by zzz in their auth0 settings?

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach should be a separation between these:

- Unergonomic web site (Client A) - which uses the implicit flow
- Web API
- Client B (your command line) - which uses a different flow

In Auth0 you should configure a new OAuth Client Entry for Client B, which should probably use a different flow - perhaps the password grant you mention.

You will at least be able to get a token in this manner. Whether the API accepts calls from you may depend on other design aspects.

Comment: This sounds like it’s only something the admin of the website/Web API can do, not me as a plain user?

Comment: Yes - but if there is a need to use a different flow - eg for an automated test client - then it is common to do this - at least in test environments. Otherwise you are forced to develop complex and unreliable code,bad you are finding.